# Converting .txt file with tab seperation to xlsx via python3

Tags: python, excel

Level: super-noob

I have been trying to convert a .txt file to .xlsx using a combination of csv & openpyxl & xlsxwriter modules.

My first column is an identity that should be saved as a string
Columns 2-21 are then all numbers.

How can I load up my .txt file.
Identify the proper columns as numbers
and then save the file as an xlsx?

So far I'm at:

```
import csv
import openpyxl

input_file = "C:/1.txt"
output_file = "C:/1.xlsx"

new_wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = new_wb.worksheets[0]
read_file = csv.reader(input_file, delimitter="\t")
```

I have read people using enumerate to gun through an excel file online but I'm not sure how this function exactly works... but if someone can help me here it will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate over each row in csv file and append that row to excel worksheet.

This could be helpful:

```
import csv
import openpyxl

input_file = 'path/to/inputfile.txt'
output_file = 'path/to/outputfile.xls'

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

with open(input_file, 'rb') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        ws.append(row)

wb.save(output_file)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answer. The only problem here is that my csv file is being read as integers when I need specific columns to be read as integers.

Comment: You could consider reading the csv in using pandas, in which you have a lot of control over how individual columns are parsed. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html